# Collection Modified exception when saving isolated storage settings in windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

This is my code for saving settings in isolated storage.

```
  public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;

        // If the key exists
        if (settings.Contains(Key))
        {
            // If the value has changed
            if (settings[Key] != value)
            {
                // Store the new value
                settings[Key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise create the key.
        else
        {
            settings.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        return valueChanged;
    }

 public void SaveCurrentTime()
    {

        if (AddOrUpdateValue("DeactivateTime", DateTimeOffset.Now))
        {
            settings.Save();
        }
    }
```

But sometimes I am getting collection modified exception.Find below exception details

> [Type]:[InvalidOperationException] [ExceptionMessage]:[Collection was
>   modified; enumeration operation may not execute.] [StackTrace]:[    at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()    at
>   WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, Object graph)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(Stream
>   stream, Object graph)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Save()

Can anyone tell me where it is going wrong?

Comment: This exception can occur when you are looping in a list/enumeration and in between the list was modified. Here I see a new item being added to `settings`. Do you think `settings` is being accessed somewhere else while this happens?

Comment: No, It is not being accessed anywhere.

Comment: i had similar problem, it turns out that i had to set DataContract Attributes (to my object), please give it a try

Comment: Any news on this topic? I have similar problems with my app :/